# How to find output of JS each function within a JS string variable (i.e., javascript interpolation)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, interpolation

For context, `gon.jbuilder` is a nested JSON that represents a `has_many` relationship between `lenders` and their `inventories`.

```
gon.jbuilder = [
  {
     "name": "John Doe", 
     "age": 29,
     "inventories": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "nail"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "hammer"},
        ...
     ]
  },
  {
     "name": "Jane Smith", 
     "age": 31,
     "inventories": [
        {"id": 3, "name": "picture"},
        {"id": 4, "name": "frame"},
        ...
     ]
  }
]
```

I'm using the Google Maps api to make a marker for each `lender` and then display in the infowindow for each `lender` all his/her `inventories`. This requires a `each` loop inside the content for the infowindow, which I'm don't know how to do. I need something like this:

```
$.each( gon.jbuilder, function (counter, lender) { 
   // draw the marker for each lender
   // establish an info window for each lender

   // below per Google API docs should be the content that goes into the info window, not sure how to interpolate the each correctly
      var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ lender.name + '</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<ul>' +
        $.each( lender, function (counter, inventory) {
          '<li>' + inventory.name + '</li'>
        }; + 
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.each` returns the object you iterated over, not what the interation function returns. Plus, your function doesn't return anything -- it performs a concatenation, but doesn't return it.

You can use `$.map`, which returns all the results in an array, and then use `.join` to concatenate them into a string.

```
  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ lender.name + '</h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<ul>' +
    $.map( lender.inventories, function (inventory, counter) {
      return '<li>' + inventory.name + '</li>';
    }).join('') + 
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! this is my first foray into JS so it's all very new. BTW, I think I made an error and it should be `$.map( lender.inventories...` since `lender.inventories` is the array of child objects I actually want to iterate over to get the names of. On this, it's still not working. Within the revised `$map`, I have a  `console.log(inventory)` and the output is not an object, but rather just a number, as in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... corresponding to each object in the array. What is causing this? How can I actually get the child object so I can return an attribute of the child object?

Comment: I had the arguments to the mapping function backwards. Annoyingly, `$.map` and `$.each` have different orders.

Comment: wow...that must be very obnoxious to remember. thanks so much! I actually have one more question on this... it's also annoying that I think of these as they happen. I'm happy to open another question if you'd like. I need to also make each `inventory.name` clickable, I'm thinking the right way of doing this is by setting an `id` for the `<li>` in which case I'd write: `return '<li id="' + inventory.name + '">' + inventory.name + '</li>';` does that seem right?

Comment: Adding an ID doesn't make them clickable, you have to bind a click handler. You can use `$(document).on("click", "#content li", function() ...)` to make them clickable.

Comment: right sorry i meant, i would do that of course, but the ID is what I would put in the middle of the click handler function, so in this case $(document).on("click", "#inventory.name", function() ... )

Comment: There's no need to create a separate click handler for each LI. Just use a single handler for a selector that matches all of them.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is what I want to do is when an inventory item is clicked, then that item gets added to a cart (`localStorage`), so it has to be unique for each item, I think?

Comment: No, you use `$(this)` to get the element you clicked on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59845/discussion-between-james-and-barmar).